# Do bases only matter when converting between them?

Tags: number-theory

I've been curious for a while why base-2 ie binary(and thus all other bases) can't esentially contain themselves? In any base higher than 2,3,4... you can write "2","3","4".... but in what we call and reference as base 2 we aren't able to write "2" etc. Is it possible to express the idea of base 2 within the binary system itself, where 2 is unavailable/represented instead as 10? Or does any of it only come to matter when you want to think in different bases?

Comment: Well, the definition of base $n$ is that you're allowed to use the numbers between $0$ and $n-1$ in writing the numbers ... And therefore, the "name" of the base in its own base is always $10_b = 1\times b^1 + 0 \times b^0$ where $b$ is the base. So, I don't really understand what's unclear about this.

Comment: Coming from a planet where people have 16 fingers (i.e. use hexadecimal): "Is it possible to express the idea of base A within the decimal system itself, where A is unavailable/represented instead as 10?"

Comment: What would come after A brian? 10? Now representing 11 in decimal? Hmm. This makes me want to say they do only ever matter when converting them? With Matti's definition we essentially define all bases via the decimal system anyway and it becomes a circular argument?